# Extract property name and nullable value from lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, nullable

I'm using a lambda expression and need to extract the property name and value:

```
  public MyMapping(Expression<Func<TEntity, int?>> expression)
    {
        this.expression = expression;

        if (this.expression != null)
        {
            if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
            {
                this.expressionMemberName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                var op = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
                this.expressionMemberName = ((MemberExpression)op).Member.Name;
            }          
        }
    }
```

The expression is setup as follows:

```
this.MyProperty(m => m.NumberOfDays.Value);
```

I want the following:

```
 var propertyName = this.expressionMemberName;

 var value = this.expression.Compile()(instance);
```

Because my property is nullable, I get an exception when it tries to compile the expression. Also propertyName is set to "Value" instead of NumberOfDays.

How would I go about getting this data and getting the expression to coompile?

Comment: ok...found the issue after a few hours! Since the field is nullable I can leave off the .Value - the mapping should read- this.MyProperty(m => m.NumberOfDays);

Comment: Then you should post that as an answer and then accept it, when you can.

Answer (score 0):

See this post ([Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression/)) for extracting property names from Expressions.  Also see [this gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220748/1037948) for nested/subproperties, i.e. `Thing1.Thing2` from `o => o.Thing1.Thing2`.